# How to disable a custom range without style changes using Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm have the range:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mb-4 col-sm-5">
    <input type="range" class="custom-range" min="0" max="10" value="10" id="range-input" style="width: 100%">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And I want to disable it (it should still *look the same*, but the user **can't interact with it anymore**), but **without change the style**. For example:

[image: Ranges example]

In the image, the **one at the top is enabled**, and **the one at the bottom is disabled**; I want to **disable it while maintaining the styling of the top range**.

I tried to recreate the original styling manually, but I was not successful:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <style>
    input[type=range]:disabled {
      background-color: blue;
      color: blue;
      background: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mb-4 col-sm-5">
    <input type="range" class="custom-range" min="0" max="10" value="10" id="range-input" style="width: 100%" disabled>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Apart from that, I couldn't find any other possible solution in my research.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'm sorry, I forgot to mention what I had tried, I added it to the question.

Comment: Styling a range input is not that easy, especially because they don't look the same across different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, etc.). I suggest you rely on some external resources such as https://www.cssportal.com/style-input-range/ to build all the CSS that is needed for the task.

Comment: "How" disabled do you actually need it to be? Setting `pointer-events: none`, and adding `tabindex="-1"`, gets you an element that still _looks_ the same, but the user can't interact with any more (at least via mouse click / tap, and they can't focus it for keyboard control either - not sure if there is anything else?) Since no `name` attribute is set, the field would not become part of a form submission data set to begin with here - if that's different in your real use case, you could also remove (and re-set) a `name`, when you toggle the `tabindex` on and off.

Comment: @CBroe `pointer-events: none` was exactly what I needed! Could you please convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: Sure, happy to. (But if you do not set `tabindex="-1"` as well, then the user might still be able to reach the element by [tab]-ing through the elements on the site, and once it gets focus this way, they will be able to modify the value using their cursor keys.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How" disabled do you actually need it to be?

Setting `pointer-events: none`, and adding `tabindex="-1"`, gets you an element that still looks the same, but the user can't interact with any more (at least via mouse click / tap, and they can't focus it for keyboard control either - not sure if there is anything else?)

Since no `name` attribute is set, the field would not become part of a form submission data set to begin with here - if that's different in your real use case, you could also remove (and re-set) a name, when you toggle the tabindex on and off.